# What exactly does this “palm tree” icon under “Recent” in iPhoto (9.6.1) represent? Is there a way to disable it?

Tags: macos, photos.app

I’m sorting through photos in iPhoto (version 9.6.1) on my Mac OS X 10.11.6 (El Capitan) machine and just noticed this odd “palm tree” icon listed under “Recent” and utterly have no idea what it represents or means.

In my case it’s showing exactly one—seemingly arbitrary—photo from March 7, 2016 and for the life of me I have utterly no idea why this would be the case; see screenshot below.

The “sorting” I am doing encompasses simply renaming photos so they have a human readable name—instead of `DSCN_` or `IMG_` and such—and nothing else. I’ve rebuilt the iPhoto database by holding down the <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd> keys a few times, but it doesn’t seem to affect anything.

Does anybody know what it means? Is there any simple way to disable it? Some online forums seem to suggest exporting all photos (!) and reimporting them again (!!!) which seems insane to me. Heck, I’m planning on moving over to the newer Photos app when the dust settles on my iPhoto sorting so I’m sure *that* would clear things up.

What what the heck does this thing mean now in iPhoto?

[image: Screenshot of iPhoto sidebar with the odd “palm tree” icon.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting the original question—and noticing the same palm tree icon appears at the top of the sidebar list under “Library” under the name “Events”—I experimented and it seems that the the listing under “Recent” represents the last batch of event photos you have viewed. Very odd feature if you ask me.